# How to fire an event to trigger Windows scheduled jobs

Tags: java, windows

I am so new to Windows platform that I can not even find the correct keywords to google. I need write a Java program to do Task-A, and upon finishing, fire an event to trigger a scheduled job in Windows Task Scheduler to start a Python program to do Task-B.

Can anyone help show me a tutorial or sample code to fire an event in Java(or Python) that can be captured by Task Scheduler? Many thanks!

[image]

Comment: An alternative to firing an event to trigger the scheduled task would be to simply execute the scheduled task using the windows command SCHTASKS.  You can see the command line syntax by running "schtasks /Run /?" from a command prompt.

Comment: @Palamino This is certainly helpful. Many thanks!